# Visual C# 2010: Avoiding dependency hell in solution with multiple dependent projects (involving Google Calendar v3)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependencies, google-calendar-api, projects-and-solutions

## Facts

I've got two VS2010 C# single-project solutions:

1. Class Library which provides functionality regarding to managing a calendar. Let's call it a *Manager*. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ldjhtn4yxajss7y/Manager.png
2. Console Application which would like to use this functionality. I'll refer to it as *Client*. https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4xiuy598ixereg/Client.png

---

## Goals

Both projects are under development, so it would be perfect if I could comfortably work on both of them in one solution, compiling them both at the same time every modification. That way development is fast and easy, because *Find definition* works, I can *Refactor -> Rename* in both projects at once, debugging a problem is more precise.

---

## Ideas

... I came up with, none of which worked as flawlessly as intended, every one of which having its shortcomings.

---

#### 1. Add existing *Manager* project into *Client* solution (as a reference)

My personal dream. It would look like this: dropbox.com/s/od7f2n12vw48xdx/Idea1.png

> Goals achieved:
>
> - Building *Client* forces *Manager* to be build from the latest code as well
> - Can develop both projects in one solution

> Goals not achieved:
>
> - 

Perfect! But...

> Unexpected problems:
>
> - Visual Studio forces me to reference ALL libraries used in Manager, along with its app.config file for binding redirects. This creates a mess, because in both projects there is copied list of assemblies in *References*, which needs to be manually maintained - and even if I used NuGet automation, it's still too much redundancy; copying everything twice is not what I expect a Class Library to behave
>     dropbox.com/s/xvrl639f5z9sw54/Idea1Problem.png

That led me to other workaround-ideas:

---

#### 2. Rewrite *Manager* Class Library to use only REST HTTP communication

> Goals achieved:
>
> - Same as Idea 1, which is good
> - Only one dependency - the *Manager* assembly, which is even better

> Cons:
>
> - No sense rewriting an already complex, full-blown `CalendarService` class which is already provided by Google, is there?
> - Development will take lots and lots more time

> Foreseeable problems:
>
> - I have a hunch I would end up with more than one required dependency in the *Client* project *anyways*
> - In that case I should have sticked with Idea 1, and any time spent on this idea would be totally wasted

---

#### 3. Demote *Manager* to a Console Application. Keep it and *Client* separate and independent

Manager would be a daemon which awaits commands while active, executes them and stays open until *exit* is requested, much like `cmd` in Windows. A *Mediator*/*Translator* man-in-the-middle project would then be needed to connect *Client* with *Manager*, which would provide a class responsible for:

- Starting and maintaining the *Manager* application
- Giving *Client* the possibility to call methods like `Mediator.InsertEvent(Description,StartDate,Duration)` in *Client's* source code
- Translating those calls into *Manager* commands, e.g. `ManagerProcess.WriteLine("insert description start duration")`
- Parsing its result and communicating it to *Client*

> Goals achieved:
>
> - Dependency hell avoided = main enemy conquered
> - Client works as intended

But...

> Goals not achieved:
>
> - Projects not connected with one solution with all of shortcomings resulting from that

> Cons:
>
> - Need to maintain a third project serving as an intercommunication layer
> - Increased time of development, but probably less so than while going for Idea 2
> - If Client becomes a daemon itself during the development, there will be two background apps running, while one should be easily enough to get the job done

---

#### 4. Go one step further and make a Windows Service out of *Mediator*

> Goals achieved:
>
> - Same as Idea 3
> - Not sure about that, but *Mediator* class would not be needed - calls could probably be made straight to the service

> Goals not achieved:
>
> - Projects not connected with one solution with all of shortcomings resulting from that

> Cons:
>
> - Two words: *Need*. *Admin*. *Rights*. Well, three words: *Would*. *Be*. *An*. *Overkill*. *For*. *As*. *Simple*. *App*. *As*. *This*. *To*. *Require*. *Admin*. *Rights*.
> - If Client becomes a daemon itself during the development, there will be two background apps running, while one should be easily enough to get the job done

---

#### 5. Abandon hopes for in-memory interactions and communicate *Client* with *Manager* via physical iCalendar files

*Client* creates an .ics file with event to be inserted, starts *Manager* with the .ics's filepath as argument, *Manager* inserts the event

> Goals achieved:
>
> - ... Have a *Client* project which can put something into a Calendar?

> Goals not achieved:
>
> - Projects not connected with one solution with all of shortcomings resulting from that

> Cons:
>
> - Interaction by hard disk. Have mercy...
> - *Manager* would be logging-in every time it was called to create or update a Calendar event

An idea nevertheless.

---

## What I need from you

Either:

- A guidance of how to deal with the problem in Idea 1
- Pointing me which of the remaining Ideas would be the most reasonable to go with (or how to improve them)
- Another idea if those above don't just cut it and you know a better way

---

## Sorry

For making this question a lecture, I really visioned it to be explainable in five sentences. Failed at that ;)

Comment: In Idea 1 there are two links I couldn't add (I'm new as a question-asker here, and so I'm limited to two links and no pictures), so I pasted them as text. Here they are clickable for your convenience, though: [Idea1.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/od7f2n12vw48xdx/Idea1.png) [Idea1Problem.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xvrl639f5z9sw54/Idea1Problem.png)

Comment: This is a 900 word essay.  Please be more concise.  What do we **need** to know to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to develop a class library and simultaneously develop an application that is dependent on that class library.

My recommendation would be to try this:

1. Develop the application first, while making the code that you intend to include in your class library as reusable as possible.
2. Once you have you have finished developing the classes/ interfaces that you intend to include in your class library, separate that code out into a separate library which your application references.

For the sake of simplicity, I'm suggesting this modified approach as apposed to implementing a third assembly which could implement a wrapper object for your references.

Check out Jeff Atwoods post on [The Rule of Three](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/07/rule-of-three.html) to get a sense for what I mean.

The type of reusable code you're looking to develop in your library will be an evolving process that will involve much more thought and rework than that of your application. That doesn't mean that its a bad idea to begin said code as modular components inside your existing application.

Comment: After four years of this question being forgotten I've returned to reevaluate. Back then I didn't accept any answer because I didn't like any of them, but now I am a much more experienced developer, who asked about a single one advice which influenced him the most, needs to come here and say: "Yours, RangerPick". Until them I was trying to generalise, abstract and extract common functionaly out of a single application with single use. The Rule of Three... liberated me ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you need to share assemblies is that you have shared logic. What I would do is introduce a third assembly/project, called Core or something similar, and centralize/unify your shared logic there... Make Core a wrapper around the references and expose only your methods. Then use the client and manager to reference that project and call those methods.

Instead of:

```
client  --> tons of references
manager --> tons of references
```

You get:

```
core    --> tons of references
client  --> core
manager --> core
```

Comment: In what I presented Manager was supposed to provide the functionality you called as Core. I still have the same problem - the Client using Core / Manager forces me to add all of the Core's / Manager's references. How to deal with that? "core --> tons of references + client --> core" Would be perfect for me. But now I reached the point of "core --> tons of references + client --> core and core's references I can't get rid of"

Comment: That means your core is still exposing the referenced classes. It should not. You should abstract the classes with wrappers of your own and expose those to Client. This would enable you in the future to change technologies in Core and not have to recode Client.

Comment: I know it's been a long time ago, but still I forgot to thank you for this piece of knowledge you fed me here. Now, 4 years later, each time I inherit a class, I still remember this advice and where I learned it :)

Comment: @ensisNoctis hah, that's awesome & what Stack Overflow is all about. :)